# Upgrading Swift Vapor Project to Swift 4 / Catalina result in lots of undeclared types

Tags: swift, openssl, vapor, vapor-fluent

I have a project in swift vapor that was working fine with swift 3 in Mojave, but now on Catalina I was getting some errors so Im trying to update it.

The first thing I did was to update the fluent and vapor swift packages:
    package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "2.4.0")),
    package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "2.1.0")),

When I try to build the project I'm getting a bunch of unresolved types for the Crypto package. If I'm not mistaken this are OpenSSL types, but have no idea how to add fix this.

Any help is greatly appreciate it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, for Xcode 11 on MacOS Catalina vapor & fluent version 3 as of minimum is required.